# New 'hungarian' tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

I just asked this new question: [English translation for Kockásfülű Nyúl (Hungarian)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273362/english-translation-for-kock%C3%A1sf%C3%BCl%C5%B1-ny%C3%BAl-hungarian)

for which I'd like to use the 'hungarian' tag which doesn't exist at this time and I don't have enough reputation on this site to create it. Can someone with sufficient reputation please create the tag and add it to my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tags are meant to provide useful categorizations of the questions.  Honestly I think we could do without most or all of the existing language-name tags (I found tags for [german](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german), [french](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french), [japanese](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese), [chinese](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese), [spanish](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish), and [italian](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian) just by looking at a few questions already tagged with [translation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)).

I don't think having a tag with the originating language substantially assists people in finding questions; it's quite sufficient to mention in the text of the question what language you're coming from.

Comment: I thought adding a specific source language tag would help narrowing down searches. I do enjoy reading translations of various phrases but it's only meaningful to me when I understand the source language, too.

Comment: @xxbbcc, I certainly understand and sympathize with your reasoning on that, I just happen to disagree with it.  :-)  Perhaps it's because I don't really speak any other languages.  (I do know a fair bit of French, German, and Latin vocabulary, but I could not carry on a conversation in any of them.)

Comment: The *latin* and *french* tags certainly, and *german* probably, are useful because of the effects those languages have had on English. It is unfortunate that many people therefore assume that any translation question needs a language tag.

Comment: @TimLymington It wasn't ever my understanding that the other-language tags were for translation, but rather for English words that had *originated* in that language. That's how I understood Latin and Greek, for example.

Comment: @TimLymington Why do you think it's wrong to assume that? To me it seems that a plain translation tag is not that useful - one only knows the target language (implied by being on this SE site). When I saw those language tags you mention, that was the _very first_ thing I thought of. Other languages' effects on English didn't even come to mind.

Comment: @xxbbcc:M that is precisely my point. This is *not* a translation site, so the original language is neither necessary nor helpful. Translation questions can be on-topic and useful, but only by virtue of the English phrase; Tagging them by language would be exactly what we want to discourage.

Comment: @TimLymington I think SE _should_ be used for translation (to English and within limits) - it's vote system is really useful in picking correct translations and offering multiple possible options. Translating a phrase can be excessively difficult between languages (not talking about dictionary words). I guess I see your point, though, and I reluctantly agree. A language tag would help _browsing_ translations but not in looking for a specifc phrase.

Comment: @xxbbcc, On many translation-tagged questions, the person offering the "best" translation has zero knowledge of how to speak the originating language.  If someone says "we have a saying that translates directly as 'The dog can't smell its own bad breath' which is used when people refuse to admit that their own ideas are stupid or unusable", I don't need to know what the original language is to come up with English equivalent sayings.  I don't view that as a "translation" question really, but as a "how do I express this concept idiomatically in English" question.

Comment: @Hellion I guess that's what I meant when I said translation within limits.